# In a Banach Space $V$, proof that $A_V = B_V$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, banach-spaces

Let V be a Banach Space. Define $$\delta_V (t) = \inf \left\{ 1 - \frac{\|x+y\|}{2}: \|x\| = \|y\| = 1, \|x-y\| = t \right\}, \ \ \ \ t \in [0,2].$$ Consider
$$ A_V = \inf \left \{ \frac{4 - \|x+y\|^2}{\|x-y\|^2} : \|x\| = \|y\| = 1, x \neq y \right\} $$ and 
$$ B_V = \inf \left\{ 4 \frac{1 - (1-\delta_V(t))^2}{t^2} : 0 < t \leq 2 \right\}.$$
Then $A_V = B_V$.

*Proof.*  Let $x,y \in V$ s.t. $\|x\| = \|y\| = 1$ and $\|x-y\| = t$, as, by definition, $\delta_V(t) \leq 1 - \frac{\|x+y\|}{2} $, we have
$$ (1 - \delta_V(t))^2 \geq   \frac{\|x+y\|^2}{4} \Rightarrow 4 (1 - (1 - \delta_V(t))^2 ) \leq 4 - \|x+y\|^2$$
As $t^2 = \|x-y\|^2$, we have
$$ \frac{4(1-(1 - \delta_V(t))^2)}{t^2} \leq \frac{4 - \|x+y\|^2}{\|x-y\|^2} \Rightarrow B_V \leq A_V $$
By the other side, given $0 < t \leq 2$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $x,y \in V$ st $\|x\| = \|y\| = 1$ and $\|x-y\| = t$ satisfying:
$$ 1 - \frac{\|x+y\|}{2} \leq \delta_V(t) + \epsilon t^2 \Rightarrow 2 - \|x+y\| \leq 2 \delta_V(t) + 2 \epsilon t^2 $$
The next step in the proof would be showing the following inequality:
$$ 4 - \|x+y\|^2 \leq 4(\delta_V(t) + \epsilon t^2 (2 - \delta_V(t))) $$
However, I can't see why it's true. I would appreciate a hint.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot follow why you want that last inequality. But here is something that works.

By definition of $\delta_V(t)$, you have
$$
\delta_V(t)\leq\frac{2-\|x+y\|}2,
$$
that is $$\|x+y\|\leq 2-2\delta_V(t).$$ Also, $$2+\|x+y\|\leq2+\|x\|+\|y\|=4.$$

Then
\begin{align}
4-\|x+y\|^2&=(2+\|x+y\|)(2-\|x+y\|)
\leq(2+\|x+y\|)(2\delta_V(t)+2\epsilon t^2)\\ \ \\
&\leq(2+\|x+y\|)2\delta_V(t)+8\epsilon t^2\\ \ \\
&\leq(2+2-2\delta_V(t))2\delta_V(t)+8\epsilon t^2\\ \ \\
&=8\delta_V(t)-4\delta_V(t)^2+8\epsilon t^2\\ \ \\
&=4(1-(1-\delta_V(t))^2)+8\epsilon t^2,
\end{align}
which implies 
$$
\frac{4-\|x+y\|^2}{\|x-y\|^2}\leq\frac{4(1-(1-\delta_V(t))^2)}{t^2}+8\epsilon.
$$